# How can i place a region insde a block template on drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a block named **block--system-branding-block.html.twig** which contains some menu items. I need to show contents from block which is placed in a region as submenu item. How can i place a region inside the block layout template. I am using Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can place anything into a block if you create it as a plugin.
If you have access to drush, you can create it simpler by using drush generate.

```
drush generate plugin:block
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the block template file, you can define the region where you want to place your content. Use the below Twig syntax to create a region using the following code:

```
{% block your_region_name %}
  {{ content }}
{% endblock %}
```

Replace "your_region_name" with the desired name for your region. The content variable will render the content of the block.